# What's the difference between this 2 type of code?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Here are 2 type of code snippets which have the same outputs.

```
char *p = "abc";
::printf("%s",p);
```

And

```
::printf("%s","abc");
```

Is there any difference as to where the "abc" string is stored in memory?

I once heard that in the second code, the "abc" string is placed by the compiler in read-only memory (the .text part?)

How to tell this difference from code if any?

Many thanks.

### Update

My current understanding is:

when we write:

```
char *p="abc"
```

Though this seems to be only a ***declarative statement***, but indeed the compiler will generate many ***imperative instructions*** for it. These instructions will allocate proper space within the stack frame of the containing method, it could be like this:

```
subl %esp, $4
```

then the address of "abc" string is moved to that allocated space, it could be like this:

```
movl $abc_string_address, -4(%ebp)
```

The "abc" string is stored in the executable file image. But where in the memory it (*i mean the string*) will be loaded totally depends on the implementation of the compiler/linker, if it is loaded into the read-only part of the process's address space (i.e. the protection bit of the memory page is flagged as read-only), then the p is a read-only pointer, if it is loaded into the r/w part, the p is writable.

Correct me if I am wrong. Now I am looking into the assembly code generated by the gcc to have a confirmation for my understanding. I'll update this thread again shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference as to where the "abc" string is stored in memory?

Nope, and that is true for both.  String literals are stored in the read-only segment.  However, if you declare your variable as a char[] it will be copied onto the stack, i.e., not read only.

Comment: @Ed, thanks. Your reply leads me to the idea that char p[] is quite different from char *p. If the string is quite long, won't it be low efficiency to allocate a char[] on the stack and copy all the chars there?

Comment: It comes down to how you intend on using it.  If you intend on modifying the string then you *must* declare it as a char[] or you will be invoking undefined behavior.  If you are just reading it/passing it around than a char* is perfectly acceptable (or better yet; declare it as a const char* if you can).

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in where the string literal is stored. The only difference is that the former also allocates space on the stack for the variable to store the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

No difference besides a char pointer allocated on the stack for the first one.

They both use a string literal, delimited by double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it won't be stored in different locations, they are all compile-time know variables, so the compiler will generate the assembly code, and the "abc" string will be on the data segment, that is initialized data. .bss section is for unitialized data.

Try compiling with gcc and the -s option. It will generate a `.s` file, which is assembly code. The "abc" variable will be under the .rodata segment, same as .data for NASM assembly.

Here's the assembly code if you don't want to do the work:

This is for char* c = "abc"; printf("%s\n", c);
 Note how this file has more lines of code than the other one, since this code allocates a pointer variable, and print this variable, the other solution doesn't use a variable, it justs references a static memory address.

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "abc"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $.LC0, 28(%esp)
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

And this is for printf("abc\n");

```
    .file   "test2.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "abc"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

**To your edit:**

I don't think any compiler would put `p` on a read-only memory, since you declared it as a variable on the code, it's not a hidden/protected variable generated by the compiler, it's a variable you can use whenever you want.

If you do `char* p = "abc";` the compiler will sub the pointer's size to the stack, and on the later instruction, it will insert the memory address of the "abc" string (now this is put into read only) into the register, and if the compiler needs register, save it's value to the stack.

If you do `printf("abc");` no variable will be alocated, since the compiler knows the string's value at compile time, so it just inserts a number there (relative to the start of the executable file) and it can read the content of that part of the memory.
 In this option, you can compile it, generate a .exe, then use a HEX editor, and search for the "abc" string, and change it to "cba" or whatever (probably it will be one of the first lines or one of the last), if the compiler generates a simple .exe like this, which is probable.

Comment: Dude... i HAVE to get my first correct answer, so i did it fast.. lol. Btw, just realized that if you do a `printf` ending with `\n`, the compiler uses the puts function... pretty nice.

Comment: It's quite strange that puts() gets its input from the (%esp).

Comment: @smwikipedia: you can mess with esp as much as you want, you shouldn't use ebp, that'swhy it is saved on the first isntruction. the `push` instruction does exactly what the code did using 2 lines: it sub from the stack the size of the variable, and move to that memory address, so what the code is doing is putting the "abc" address on the stack, so that `puts` can access it's parameters.